# What are ways to block direct access to files on apache but allow them through scripts?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, config

If I type in the direct path to any of the content in my server directory I can see and download the file without being logged in. (example I have a directory foo with a file bar.jpg in it. If I type into the search bar "ip:port/foo/bar.jpg I can see the picture without needing to go through the pages I created). I know it would be difficult to access but if it can happen it eventually will. Is there a way that allows my php script to access files and display them in a webpage but not allow any direct access to the content on my server when typed in?﻿ I have tried .htaccess files and directly altering the server config in apache, my access looks like this:

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\RootFolder\Login System">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?Family [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
</Directory>
```

The problem here is that it randomly blocks some images in my page while allowing others through:

```
GET http://localhost/Family/IMG_2436.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

I have been bashing my head in trying to get this to work so that if someone types in a direct link they get an access denied while accessing through my php page would just show the picture or file. Is there any way to do this? ps I'm using a windows base

Comment: Actually looking into the browser developer mode it looks like the reason it allows some files and not others is because they are cached versions. Which is wierd because with other configurations it doesn't even show that.